# Invalid identifier when use alternate name of column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, average

I have some lines of code, but it won't work somehow. I want to call this column round() the name "Diem" to use  it later, but Diem >= 1 make it invalid identifier. Can somebody please help?

```
select id, name, round(avg(
decode(grade, 'A+', 4.5,'A', 4,
'A-',3.5, 'B+',3, 'B',2.5, 'B-', 2,
'C+', 1.5, 'C', 1, 'C-',0.5
)), 1) as ***DIEM***
from takes t join student s 
using (id)
where tot_cred >= 128
and ***DIEM*** >= 1
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter on the result of an aggregate function: for this, you need to use a `having` clause rather than a `where` clause.

Also, you cannot access an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause (nor in the `having` clause in Oracle).

You need to either repeat the expression or use a derived table (subquery or cte).

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    round(avg(decode(grade, 'A+', 4.5,'A', 4, ...)), 1) as diem
from takes t 
inner join student s using (id)
where tot_cred >= 128
group by id, name
having round(avg(decode(grade, 'A+', 4.5,'A', 4, ...)), 1) >= 1
```

Here, it might be simpler to move the decoding to a subquery. Assuming that `grades` comes from the `takes` table:

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    round(avg(t.new_grade), 1) as diem
from (
    select t.*, decode(grade, 'A+', 4.5, 'A', 4, ...) as new_grade
    from takes t
) t 
inner join student s using (id)
where tot_cred >= 128
group by id, name
having round(avg(t.new_grade), 1) >= 1
```

Comment: Thank you. The first one works though i still can't call the round() with short name. The second one meets exactly what i'm asking,` "new_grade" invalid identifier`.